# If there is no incentive to have multiple rollup nodes then "A rollup is safe as long as there is at least one honest participant"-means its not safe?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup

If there is no incentive to have multiple rollup nodes then "A rollup is safe as long as there is at least one honest participant" -> means its not safe, correct?

[Question from Greeneye44](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/11enw9p/comment/jctmt5m/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incentive is the security of the rollup, and of its TVL, but it is true that there is no built-in reward system to compensate node operators. That being said, such a mechanism can be implemented inside the rollup kernel. This follows the general approach of the design of Smart Rollups: rather than forcing opt-in centralized solutions upon users, we provide a programmable device allowing to address a large variety of use cases, including but not limited to these centralized solutions.

[Answer from Nomadic Labs](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/11enw9p/comment/je01xn0/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)